# search and remove empty parent nodes in kendo tree

Tags: javascript, for-loop, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am trying to simply detect and ***remove*** some empty parent nodes in my kendo tree. When i console log my tree, *i.e.* `console.log(pf);` I see a *hasChildren* property - so it must be possible...

*Btw.. I am trying to create a function to reevaluate the tree for this.. not hardcore any changes in the initialization.*

Below is my recent attempt:

```
 let pf = $("#tree").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource;  

 for (const item of pf) {
    if (pf._data[item].hasChildren = false){

        treeview.remove(item);

    }
  }
```

My tree, for instance: `console.log(pf);`

[image: init {options: {…}, _map: {…}, _prefetch: {…}, _data: init(6), _pristineData: Array(6), …} data: ƒ () fields: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] options: {data: Array(6), schema: {…}, offlineStorage: null, serverSorting: false, serverPaging: false, …} reader: init {modelBase: ƒ, model: ƒ, _dataAccessFunction: ƒ, _wrapDataAccessBase: ƒ, data: ƒ, …} transport: init {data: Array(6)} _aggregate: undefined _aggregateResult: {} _changeHandler: ƒ () _currentRangeStart: undefined _data: init(6) 0: subclass {_events: {…}, _handlers: {…}, id: "weather", text: "Weather", tree: "threat", …} 1: subclass {_events: {…}, _handlers: {…}, id: "flood", text: "Flooding", tree: "threat", …} 2: subclass {_events: {…}, _handlers: {…}, id: "quake", text: "Earthquakes", tree: "threat", …} 3: subclass {_events: {…}, _handlers: {…}, id: "fire", text: "Fires", tree: "threat", …} 4: subclass dirty: false dirtyFields: {} hasChildren: false]

Comment: Can you share your declaration of "treeview"?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the example of [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64081462/4031083), I changed it for this new question.

*Cheers*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#treeView").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: [
            {
                text: "Item 1",
                items: [
                    { text: "Item 1.1" },
                    { text: "Item 1.2" }
                ]
            },
            { text: "Item 2" },
            { text: "Item 3" },
            {
                text: "Item 4",
                items: [
                    { text: "Item 4.1" },
                    { text: "Item 4.2" }
                ]
            },
        ]
    });
    
    
    var treeView = $("#treeView").data("kendoTreeView");
     
    function removeTreeviewEmptyNodes(thisTreeView, nodes) {
      
      for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {        
        if (!nodes[i].hasChildren) {
          console.log(nodes[i].text + " removed");
          thisTreeView.remove(thisTreeView.findByUid(nodes[i].uid));
        } else {
          console.log(nodes[i].text);
        }
        
      }
      
    }
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      removeTreeviewEmptyNodes(treeView, treeView.dataSource.view());
    }, 3000);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.915/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.915/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


<ul id="treeView">

</ul>
<br><b>Wait 3 seconds for empty nodes to be removed</b>
```